# FragmentManager.beginTransaction() on null object reference when trying to add new dialogFragment to a exsisting dialogfragmen whicht is on a fragment

Tags: java, android, dialogfragment, fragmentmanager

this is not a duplicate question as the occurrence of the issue is different.. as i am only experiencing this behavior when i try to do exact what i have mentioned(layout order wise)

i am trying to create a new dialog fragment trough another dialog fragment. when i try to do that it throws an `error`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.beginTransaction()' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:142)
```

---

this is the related code

```
ForgotPasswordFailedFragment forgotPasswordFailedFragment = new ForgotPasswordFailedFragment();
        forgotPasswordFailedFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Password Reset Failed");
```

---

so my view order is something like this..

> mainActivity -> fragment -> dialogfragment -> dialogfragment (i'am trying to get this)

i have tried mentioned answers and tease are the  errors that occurred for each change...

ForgotPswrdSuccessFragment forgotPswrdSuccessFragment = new ForgotPswrdSuccessFragment();
forgotPswrdSuccessFragment.show(requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "Password Reset Failed");

this throws

```
 Fragment ForgotPasswordDFragment{725811b} not attached to an activity.
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.requireActivity(Fragment.java:724)
            at *********.SignIn.ForgotPassword.ForgotPasswordDFragment.showSuccessDialog(ForgotPasswordDFragment.java:85)
```

ForgotPasswordDFragment is a dialog fragment which is on a fragment 
and i am calling another dialogfragment from (ForgotPasswordDFragment)  there..and now that action is throwing above mentioned eror

for this

```
forgotPswrdSuccessFragment.show(this.getChildFragmentManager(), "Password Reset Failed");
```

the exception is

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment has not been attached yet.
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiateChildFragmentManager(Fragment.java:2383)

Comment: Try replacing getFragmentManager() to getSupportFragmentManager();

Comment: I think your DialogFragment is a type of support.v4.app and for this you should be using getSupportFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager().

Comment: thanks for replying ..i  cannot access getSupportFragmentManager().. i entered my layout order into the question ..

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Sha this might be helpful:

```
YourDialog yourDialog = YourDialog.newInstance(); 
yourDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"DialogFragment");
```

Comment: thanks for the reply..but  this does not work..i have mentioned my view order

Answer (score 0):

FragmentManager will be null until it is attached to the activity.

So use below code ,

If it is a nested Fragment use `this.getChildFragmentManager()` for your fragment class

else use `getActivity().getFragmentManager()` or `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Comment: i tried your answer..i have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

`getFragmentManager()` might return null, if the fragment is not attached to a context. This could result in uncaught exceptions by passing a null reference, as the stack trace already mentioned. The most direct way would be to wrap `getFragmentManager()` into a not-null-condition

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();

if (manager != null) {
    //your code
}
```

However, to avoid blind null passengers in your code, consider using `getSupportFragmentManager()`. This method is not directly callable on a fragment. So you have to call `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` or `requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` respectively.

Comment: thanks for the reply..i have update my code to according to your suggestion of checking null..thanks for that..i have tried other answers but no luck..i have updated my question

Comment: to show a fragment via `FragmentSupportManager` call `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new forgotPswrdSuccessFragment()).commit();` you actually don't need to instantiate the new fragment instance, despite it's a good way to do so. And don't forget to wrap this in a not-null clause also, `getActivity` might return null.

Comment: for more detail, `getActivity()` and `requireActivity()` do almost the same thing. The difference is that `requireActivity()` throws an exception while `getActivity()` just returns null

Comment: ..but my issue still remains .. i have updated the question ..can you please give a look..